# Log4j : Multiple loggers, levels and appenders

Tags: log4j

I am having trouble with duplicate log messages when writing to multiple log files using log4j.

At present I am trying to log `INFO` level data (and upwards) for the specific logger named **foobar** in my `foo.log` file and then all `WARN` level log messages (and upwards) for **all loggers** in the `bar.log` file.

As a result of this, duplicate log messages were written to the `foo.log` file (each line was logged twice) and after some quick research I found that the suggestion to fix this was to add `log4j.additivity.foobar=false` to my properties file.

The problem with this is that although it stops duplicate lines, the `WARN` message from the **foobar** logger are never written to the `bar.log` file.

**My log4j properties file is as follows:**

```
log4j.rootLogger = WARN, FOO, BAR
log4j.logger.foobar = INFO, FOO
log4j.additivity.foobar = false

log4j.appender.FOO = org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.FOO.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FOO.layout.ConversionPattern = %d{ISO8601} %-5p %c ~ %m%n
log4j.appender.FOO.File = foo.log

log4j.appender.BAR = org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.BAR.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.BAR.layout.ConversionPattern = %d{ISO8601} %-5p %c ~ %m%n
log4j.appender.BAR.File = bar.log
```

Does anyone know how I can write the log messages to both log files (as it was doing before I started setting the `additivity` property) and still prevent the duplicate log messages?

*Please note, this is a simplified summary of the problem. In the real world scenario there are multiple loggers and more than two log files*

Answer (score 64, accepted):

This problem can be solved in two parts.

**1. Prevent duplicate log messages**

The log messages were written twice because we listed the **FOO** appender in both the **rootLogger** and the **log4j.logger.foobar** category. So we must remove the appender and only define the logging level in category:

```
log4j.rootLogger = WARN, FOO, BAR
log4j.logger.foobar = INFO
```

This means that the **INFO** level messages from **log4j.logger.foobar** are propagated upwards to ALL of the loggers  the **appenders** in **rootLogger**, but will only be written to each log file once.

**2. Prevent INFO level message being written to bar.log**

Since all of the INFO level log messages for the **log4j.logger.foobar** category are being inherited by the appenders in **rootLogger**, we need to stop the `BAR` appender for recording the **INFO** level messages.

We can achieve this by setting the **Threshold** property on the **BAR** appender itself:

```
log4j.appender.BAR.Threshold = WARN
```

This will prevent the **INFO** level statements being logged in the **bar.log** file as it will only accept levels of **WARN** and upwards.

**So the complete log4j properties file would be as follows:**

```
log4j.rootLogger = WARN, FOO, BAR
log4j.logger.foobar = INFO

log4j.appender.FOO = org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.FOO.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FOO.layout.ConversionPattern = %d{ISO8601} %-5p %c ~ %m%n
log4j.appender.FOO.File = foo.log
log4j.appender.FOO.Threshold = INFO

log4j.appender.BAR = org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.BAR.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.BAR.layout.ConversionPattern = %d{ISO8601} %-5p %c ~ %m%n
log4j.appender.BAR.File = bar.log
log4j.appender.BAR.Threshold = WARN
```

Comment: this is all nice and well, but this is not what was asked. How does this differentiate by loggers? the original question said only `foobar` goes to foo, and all loggers including foobar goes to bar

Comment: The question asks for a solution where all `INFO` messages for the `foobar` logger goes to `foo.log` file and all `WARN` messages for all loggers goes to `bar.log` file (and also that each log message is only written once in the appropriate file).

Comment: no, __all loggers__, not just `foobar` get sent to `bar.log`. As per the question:

"At present I am trying to log `INFO` level data for the specific logger named `foobar` in my foo.log file and then all `WARN` level log messages for __all loggers__ in the bar.log file."

Comment: I don't see what we are saying differently here - except in your first sentence you don't acknowledge that **only** `WARN` level messages for **all loggers** get sent to `bar.log` (but you do in the copy & paste extract from my original question).

Comment: yea, in the solution __all loggers__ go to `foo.log`, which the question only asked that only __foobar__ is logged to `foo.log`. Basically, if there is a `WARN` message for `barfoo` logger, it should ___NOT___ go to __foobar__

Comment: OK, I understand now what you mean. When asking my question I wanted to log `INFO` level and upwards within my **foobar** logger and only `WARN` level and upwards in my other loggers. I will amend my question so that is clear.

Comment: Even so it's not clear, does a `WARN` level message for __barfoo__ logger go to `foo.log`?

Comment: I haven't worked with Java or log4j for about 3 years and it has been over 4 years since I asked and answered this question. Looking at the answer and question, I would say that `WARN` level messages for a hypothetical logger called **barfoo** would be intended to go to `bar.log`, but not `foo.log`. But this of course would depend on how you set it up.

Comment: well, according to your answer, __barfoo__ would go to both `FOO` and `BAR` appenders, meaning it would go to both `bar.log` and `foo.log`

Comment: as a more real world example, I want to have two logfiles, one for general logging, and one for a specific component I am working with . The specific component logfile must ONLY have log entrys for that component, and must have detailed logs, while the general logfile has log entries for all components, including the specific one, and should only show problems

Comment: I think you might be better served if you open a new question on Stackoverflow. I imagine there are people who will have more recent knowledge / experience who can guide you more than I can in these comments :)